# Extract the data if the first row of each id is 1 using R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

Here, I made a simple data to demonstrate what I want to do.

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
               date=c(20220311,20220315,20220317,20220514,20220517,20220518,20220519,20220613,20220618),
               disease=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1))
```

`id` stands for a personal id. `disease`=1 means that person has a disease. `disease`=0 means that person doesn't have a disease.There are 3 people in `df`.For `id` equals 1, the first row of the value of `disease` is 0. On the other hand, the first two rows of the value of `disease` for `id` 2 and 3 are 1. I want to extract the data if the first row of each id is 1.
So, I should extract the data with `id` 2 and 3. My expected output is

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(2,2,2,2,3,3),
               date=c(20220514,20220517,20220518,20220519,20220613,20220618),
               disease=c(1,1,1,0,1,1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `filter` where you select the first `row_number` and condition you want per `group_by` with `any` to get the group like this:

```r
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
               date=c(20220311,20220315,20220317,20220514,20220517,20220518,20220519,20220613,20220618),
               disease=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(any(row_number() == 1 & disease == 1))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id     date disease
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     2 20220514       1
#> 2     2 20220517       1
#> 3     2 20220518       1
#> 4     2 20220519       0
#> 5     3 20220613       1
#> 6     3 20220618       1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you only want to select the rows that meet your condition you can use this:

```r
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
               date=c(20220311,20220315,20220317,20220514,20220517,20220518,20220519,20220613,20220618),
               disease=c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == 1 & disease == 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id     date disease
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     2 20220514       1
#> 2     3 20220613       1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We could also do like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(first(disease)==1)
```

```
     id     date disease
  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1     2 20220514       1
2     2 20220517       1
3     2 20220518       1
4     2 20220519       0
5     3 20220613       1
6     3 20220618       1
```

Answer (score 3):

In `base` R you can do:

```
ids_disease <- df$id[!duplicated(df$id) & df$disease == 1]
df[df$id %in% ids_disease, ]
```